# Upload to Digital ocean server and GitHub repo in one step

Tags: git, github, digital-ocean

My code is locally setup on my machine and website is hosted on digitalocean. Right now, when i have to update any file, i upload it to digitalocean server through FTP.I want to setup the environment in a way where in one action i should be able to upload code files to digitalocean server and also to my repository on GitHUB. How i can create such a setup ?

Answer (score 3):

A better workflow, since you are using GitHub

- Make changes to your code
- [git commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) your changes and [git push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) them up to the GitHub repository
- Log onto your [Digital Ocean server either through SSH](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-connect-to-your-droplet-with-ssh) (using keys) or through the console on their website
- Directly on your server, [git pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) your website to copy the newly revised files
- Ensure the privileges are set appropriately so the files are served correctly (that is specific to the program you are using such as Apache)

There is a lot to learn, but all subjects are cornerstones of web development. Once you learn about SSH and keys, you can switch to SFTP, which is a must if you are going to use the FTP protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly edit your code on server. Connect your local editor say atom using sftp to edit source code on github and then Whenever you save your changes will be there and to push into git you can fire commits.