# Updating code on Digital Ocean via GitHub

Tags: django, github, digital-ocean

I have a Django app on Digital Ocean https://chicagocreativesnetwork.com/ which was uploaded via GitHub.

I need to make some changes to the CSS and HTML for this app, which I am doing locally and pushing to [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/ktduffyincorperated/chicagocreativesnetwork).

How do I get the pushed GitHub updates into my Digital Ocean app?

Answer (score 0):

How was the app uploaded to your Digital Ocean droplet exactly? Was the repo cloned or forked to the droplet?

**Read the Caution at the end first**

You could always go into your droplet console move to the directory where your project is in. Then do:

- *git status* (to see the state of your repo)
- then do *git fetch* (to fetch the changes from your origin to your droplet repo)
- do a *git status* again (to see how many steps your droplet is behind your remote
  repo)

if you see everything is ok and it says you are '1 commit behind master'(if you are changing for the first time after deployment)

- Go ahead and *git pull* (with github username and personal access token as **password**)
- do a final *git status* it should now say 'you are up-to date with remote'

**CAUTION** - do not **git push** anything from your droplet **console** into your remote repo even if *git status* shows files ready to be staged and committed in red.
These files are local to the droplet repo and should stay as they are. Any change you make should come from -

- Local changes pushed to your remote repository
- Going into your droplet console and **Pull**ing the changes into your droplet repository

The workflow is detailed more clearly in the following comment:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42001608/2155469